Can you find a square rational between two rational numbers?
I am trying to prove the existence of a square rational in between any two positive rational numbers; in other words, I wish to claim that
$$
\exists s^2 \in \mathbb{Q}:p<s^2<q
$$
where $\, p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $0<p<q$.
My attempt at a proof is as follows. Let $p=a/b$ and $q = c/d$ with $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now express $p$ and $q$ with a common denominator:
$$
p = \frac{ad}{bd}\,,\,q=\frac{bc}{bd}.
$$
Now ensure the denominators are square numbers:
$$
p = \frac{ad\cdot bd}{(bd)^2}\,,\,q=\frac{bc\cdot bd}{(bd)^2}.
$$
Continue in this fashion by squaring the denominators
$$
p = \frac{ad\cdot (bd)^3}{(bd)^4}\,,\,q=\frac{bc\cdot (bd)^3}{(bd)^4};
$$
$$
p = \frac{ad\cdot (bd)^7}{(bd)^8}\,,\,q=\frac{bc\cdot (bd)^7}{(bd)^8};
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
p = \frac{ad\cdot (bd)^{2^n-1}}{(bd)^{2^n}}\,,\,q=\frac{bc\cdot(bd)^{2^n-1}}{(bd)^{2^n}}.
$$
I am hoping, and cannot prove, that there will eventually be a square number between the two numerators:
$$
ad\cdot (bd)^{2^n-1} < m^2 < bc \cdot (bd)^{2^n-1}.
$$
This would then give the square number
$$
s^2 = \frac{m^2}{(bd)^{2n}}
$$
as required. Since $p<q$ then $ad <bc$. If there is not an square in between $ad$ and $bc$, would multiplication by an arbitrarily large integer, $(bd)^{2^n-1}$, guarantee the above (unproved) statement?
EDIT:
I am using the proof (assuming it exists) to construct elements of $\mathbb{R}$ so I need to proof to not make mention of their existence.

There is a rational number $s$ between $\sqrt p$ and $\sqrt q$.

You mean "$\exists s \in \mathbb{Q}:p<s^2<q$".

Welcome to Math SE. For the duplicate, I assumed, as TonyK asks, you're referring to $s\in\mathbb{Q}$. Note I found this duplicate using an Approach0 search. There are also quite a few quite a few other duplicates or near duplicates, e.g., A square of a rational between two positive real numbers ?!, Prove there is a square of a rational number between any two positive real numbers, Can I find a $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<r^2<y$?, etc.

@TonyK yes I do actually. I assumed that when writing that they were equivalent, but not so.


Let $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $0<p<q \implies \sqrt{p}<\sqrt{q} $. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ ,there exists $s\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{p}<s<\sqrt{q}\implies p <s^2<q$ $\blacksquare$

Apologies to @geetha290krm ; the proof was derived from your idea.

It wasn’t at all clear from my question but I am interested in constructing $\mathbb{R}$ from the rationals so would require a proof that does not make reference the real numbers. Some of the duplicates do this so I’ll look there
